# Efficient way of computing matrix product AXA'?

Tags: matrix, matrix-multiplication, blas

I'm currently using BLAS function DSYMM to compute `Y = AX` and then DGEMM for `YA'`, but I'm wondering is there some more efficient way of computing the matrix product AXA<sup>T</sup>, where A is an arbitrary `n×n` matrix and X is a symmetric `n×n` matrix?

Comment: Is there any repetition in your computation?  That is, are either of the terms constant for at least a few iterations?  What size matrices?