# M x S x T(M) multiplication with BLAS

Tags: c, matrix-multiplication, blas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Efficient way of computing matrix product AXA'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139933/efficient-way-of-computing-matrix-product-axa)

I have two double precision matrices:

- `M`, which has size `l ⨯ m` and no particular property;
- `S`, which has size `m ⨯ m` and is symmetric.

I would like to compute:

```
R = M ⨯ S ⨯ t(M)
```

where `t(M)` is the transpose of `M`.

Looking at the list of (C) BLAS routines I didn't find anything that directly addresses this case. What is the most efficient combination of routines, then, that would allow me to compute `R`?

Comment: Do you think, that there is something more effective then DSYMM and DGEMM (`P=MxS; R=P*t(M)`)?

Comment: *GEMM + *SYMM seems like the best you can hope to do.