# How to tell BLAS that output matrix is symmetric?

Tags: c, matrix-multiplication, blas, intel-mkl

I have two `n x k` complex matrices `A` and `B`. I need to calculate `C = A B^H`. `C` is guaranteed to be real, symmetric and all elements will be non-negative. These matrices will be pretty large so I am going to be using either CBLAS or MKL in C for this purpose. However, I cannot find a way to tell BLAS that `C` is symmetric, at least based on the quick reference document. This is important as it would halve the computation time. The `xHER2K` routine will give me a `B A^H` term which I don't want. Please suggest a way to proceed in this matter.

Comment: Have you had a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24435892/is-there-a-blas-or-lapack-subroutine-for-symmetric-matrix-multiplication-that-ta

Comment: @Fra93, that question is both unanswered and not similar to mine. The question asks about computing A^2 where A is symmetric. In my case, I need C=AB^H where A and B are not symmetric (they are not even square matrices) while C is symmetric.

Comment: Right, quoting here instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091851/optimize-blas-like-operation-aba "*Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a BLAS routine where you can claim beforehand that given two general matrices, the output matrix will be symmetric*", but  it is also an old question.

Comment: I see. I'll try and reformulate my expression to match the `AB^H + BA^H` style somehow, but I doubt it can be done. Thanks for your help! If any other user knows something then please leave a comment or an answer.

Comment: Could you please look into the below routines (which perform matrix-vector / matrix-matrix product) for the functionality which perfectly matches your requirement or elaborate on your expression?

Blas Level 2 routines
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-developer-reference-c/top/blas-and-sparse-blas-routines/blas-routines/blas-level-2-routines.html

Blas Level 3 routines
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-developer-reference-c/top/blas-and-sparse-blas-routines/blas-routines/blas-level-3-routines.html